# How to filter multiple criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

I'm trying to sort a dataframe by countries and legislative elections - in one step that is replicable for multiple different political party families.

What I did so far was to sort the main dataset into party family (parfam == '10'), "recent" elections (date > '201000'), and excluding countries with no relevant data (! country %in% nodata, nodata being a list of values I'd already created):

`eco <- filter(CMPdataset, parfam == '10' & date > '201000' & ! country %in% nodata)`

Due to some countries having multiple elections coded into the overarching dataset CMPdataset in the time-period after 2010, I went through the data manually and eliminated all the unnecessary ones by hand using:

`eco <- eco[-c(1,8,10,11,13,14,18,20,21,22,23,27,28,31,32,34,35,37), ]`

As you can see, this can be quite tedious for larger dataframes, though. So I thought I'd combine the formulae I know and came up with the following (edate is a variable with the specific election date in the format YYYY-MM-DD, I made a list of all the specific elections I include under the name included_elections):

`eco2 <- filter(CMPdataset, parfam == '10' & ! country %in% nodata & edate %in% included_elections)`

However, this yields no results, and I have no clue why! I could just stick to doing  it all by hand, but it's quite tedious and not easily replicable, which is why I'd really prefer a solution like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can u show a small reproducible example and expected output base don that

Comment: Can you provide, at a minimum, `dput(head(CMPdataset$edate))` and `dput(head(included_elections))`? The dates might be encoded differently.

Comment: @Frank 

```> dput(head(CMPdataset$edate))
structure(c(-9237, -9237, -9237, -9237, -9237, -7774), class = "Date")
> dput(head(included_elections2))
c("2014-09-14", "2013-09-09", "2011-09-15", "2011-04-17", "2013-04-27", 
"2010-06-13")```

Comment: The reason for your immediate error is that you need to convert `included_elections` to date format, `included_elections <- as.Date(included_elections)`. But @iod's approach is a better long-term solution.

Comment: @Frank thanks for the tip, this worked out well! Doesn't look like I can accept a comment as a "correct answer", though :( iod's approach would work, but in some cases, i need the second-to-last election, which is why such a general approach unfortunately doesn't work in my specific case.

Comment: Converted the comment into an answer, so that you can accept it @luca_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing the `dput` output. The reason for your immediate error is that you need to convert `included_elections` to date format:

```
included_elections <- as.Date(included_elections)
```

That said, something more systematic that incorporates the conditions you want (for example, when you want the last election and when you want the second-last), along the lines of @iod's approach, is a better long-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
CMPdataset %>% group_by(country) %>% 
filter(parfam==`10`, !country %in% nodata, date==max(edate), date>201000)
```

`date==max(date)` will filter the data frame so that within each group (i.e., country), only the row for the latest elections is kept. (also, no need for `&` between the conditions, they're all joined by `&` by default).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately due to voter data not always being available for the latest coded manifesto data because of how these datasets aren't all from the same source, I unfortunately can't use this approach :/

Comment: If you share an example of your data, I'm sure it would be easy to ensure only the latest elections that also have data are selected, without manually choosing rows.